# How to find which cells couldn't be converted to float?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

`pandas.DataFrame.astype(float)` raises `ValueError: could not convert string to float` error.

What's the best way to find which cell(s) caused this to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can first [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with some number, e.g. `1`, [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` and if value cannot be converted is filled by `NaN`. Then you check [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html). Last use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for finding columns and index with `NaN` values - it means there are obviously `string` values or other values, which cannot be converted to numeric.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b','',5],
                   'B':[4,5,6,5],
                   'C':[np.nan,8,9,7]})

print (df)
   A  B    C
0  a  4  NaN
1  b  5  8.0
2     6  9.0
3  5  5  7.0
```

```
a = (df.fillna(1).apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')))
print (a)
     A  B    C
0  NaN  4  1.0
1  NaN  5  8.0
2  NaN  6  9.0
3  5.0  5  7.0

b = (pd.isnull(a))
print (b)
       A      B      C
0   True  False  False
1   True  False  False
2   True  False  False
3  False  False  False
```

```
print (b.any())
A     True
B    False
C    False
dtype: bool

print (b.any()[b.any()].index)
Index(['A'], dtype='object')

print (b.any(axis=1))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool

print (b.any(axis=1)[b.any(axis=1)].index)
Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64')

#df is not modified
print (df)
   A  B    C
0  a  4  NaN
1  b  5  8.0
2     6  9.0
3  5  5  7.0
```

Comment: `astype(float)` would not raise `ValueError` if there's a `float('nan')` in the original `DataFrame`. So this way, I may get false positives: this code will not distinguish from the original `float('nan')` from the ones created by `to_numeric`.

Comment: Btw, I noticed that there are differences in what `astype(float)` and `to_numeric` can do. `astype(float)` would raise `ValueError` on an empty string, while `pd.to_numeric` will convert it to `NaN` by default (even without `errors='coerce'`). This doesn't cause any problem with your code though. Still, it's weird, and it certainly would affect the logic in some cases. In fact, in my case I had a bunch of `float('nan')` and a few empty strings :)

Comment: another weird thing about `pd.to_numeric` is that using `errors='ignore'` keeps the entire column unchanged if there's even a single unparseable value. I thought it would only keep unchanged those cells that could not be converted to a number. Maybe it's a bug? If not for that, we could have just checked which cells retained their original `str` type after applying `errors='ignore'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dtype` attribute to find the datatype of numpy object.
for e.g

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([[1.9, 2.987, 'abcd',1]])
 result = df.dtypes == np.float64
```

This will generate a boolean type output from where you can easily compare

```
result
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

The above output clearly states that element at index 2 & 3 is not `float type`

Comment: Isn't `astype` going to try to convert to `float`? Like if it's a string `'4.5'`, wouldn't it just convert it to `4.5`?

Comment: can you verify if strings which couldn't  be converted are `NaN`?? As for the NaN values, you need to specify how they should be converted, but you can use the `.fillna` method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply iterate over the cells using indices, and trap the error like this:

```
for r in range(df_rows):
    for c in range(df_cols):
        try:
            float(df[r][c])
        except ValueError:
             print("Conversion error at coordinates", r, c)
```

I don't terminate the loop since you want to see all the problem cells, and there might be more than one.

Comment: I hoped to avoid the for loops given that the `DataFrame` is huge. But this should work. I think you have to use `.iloc` though; otherwise, if the indexes happen to have integer labels, the iteration will be incorrect.

Comment: I don't use pandas, so this is a general-purpose suggestion-- and has the benefit of simplicity, or at least I thought so. Feel free to correct my answer.